# Remove numbering, newline, break tags from pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns containing strings with newline, break takgs and list numbering:

```
df['Side_Effects'][0]
'1.Nausea\n<br/>2.Vomiting\n<br/>3.Diarrhoea\n<br/>4.Anorexia\n<br/>5.Malaise\n<br/>6.Fever\n<br/>7.Pruritis\n<br/>8.Rash\n<br/>9.Headache\n<br/>10.Pharyngitis\n<br/>11.Cough\n<br/>'
```

First I have to remove the numberings, newline and br tags from all the strings of column.
I tried:

```
df['Side_Effects'].replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

and this:

```
df['Side_Effects'] = df['Side_Effects'].str.replace('</br>','')
```

but nothing seems to work... Would appreciate any help !!!

Comment: The `<br/>` in your code is written wrong. Also, on the first option, try switching the double backslash with a single one

Comment: @Itay thanks for the correction tip on <br/> tag, it seems to working now. But the latter one still remains the same....i mean '\n'....

Comment: What is the expected *literal string*? I understand the input you posted is a *string literal* where `\n` denotes a single LF char, right?

Comment: `df['Side_Effects'].str.replace(r'(?m)^(?:<br/>)?\d+\.|<br/>', '')` can also help, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex and `str` methods

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['1.Nausea\n<br/>2.Vomiting\n<br/>3.Diarrhoea\n<br/>4.Anorexia\n<br/>5.Malaise\n<br/>6.Fever\n<br/>7.Pruritis\n<br/>8.Rash\n<br/>9.Headache\n<br/>10.Pharyngitis\n<br/>11.Cough\n<br/>']})
df['New'] = df['Col'].str.replace('(<br/>|\d+\.)','').str.split().agg(" ".join)    #IF you need as list skip .agg(" ".join)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             Col                                 New                                            
0  1.Nausea\n<br/>2.Vomiting\n<br/>3.Diarrhoea\n<...  Nausea Vomiting Diarrhoea Anorexia Malaise Fev...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
df['Side_Effects'] = df['Side_Effects'].str.replace(r'(?m)^(?:<br/>)?\d+\.|<br/>', '').str.strip()
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0hPgN5/1)

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line (`(?m)` is an inline variant of the `re.M` / `re.MULTILINE` flag)
- `(?:<br/>)?` - an optional `<br/>` string
- `\d+\.`  - 1 or more digits and then a `.`
- `|` - or
- `<br/>` - just `<br/>` string.

The `.str.strip()` removes any  trailing whitespace.